# How can I specify a folder path when usign href with .split('href=')[0]

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, split

I have a code which working very good with this code.

```
"</td><td><a  target='_blank' href='"+ person.documentname.split('href=')[0]+"' >"+person.documentname.split('href=')[0]+"</a></td>"
```

This code working perfect as getting a person value from a .js file and write under a document column together. But my real problem is, when value become internal which same path with html folder it is working. I want to specify a external folder path, How can I integrate?

Example,

My html path is;

```
C:\folder1\example.html
```

my .js file path is

```
C:\folder1\xxx.js
```

and my file path is

```
C:\folder1\file1.pdf
```

When this situation has showen it is working because of same path which share with html, I want to add some external values, like;

```
C:\folder2\file2.pdf
```

How can I integrate my code to this path.

```
.split('href=')[0]+"
```

This .split tag not showen on a syntax which you can use flexible. By the way, I use this code with external path always, but we can share 2 way for working same folder path and external folder path.

For understand good all my html,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="new27.js"></script>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="logoDiv"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" /></div>
<form id="search_toolbar" method="get" action="/solr/select">
<input id="searchinput" type="text" name="q" value="search" size="28" maxlength="200" onfocus="searchBarOnFocus(this)" onblur="searchBarOnBlur(this)" /></form></div>
</br>
<div class="outer-container">
<div class="container">
<div class="header"><h1 class="removeBottomPadding">
</br>
&nbsp; &nbsp; 180 Days Documents         
</div>
</div><div id="dmApplicability"><h2 id="dmApplicabilityTitle" class="removeBottomPadding"></h2><p></p></div><h1></h1><ol class="steplevel0"><li><div id="d534007e87" class="step">

<div class="note"><h4 class="removeTopBottomPadding noteText">NOTE</h4>
<div class="cautionText">This Documents Downloaded From ADDs Page/Last Revision Date : dd/mm/yy </div>
</div>
<div><table class="hoverRowBackEnabled setFixedHeaderEnabled"><thead><tr><th>
</div></li></ol></div><div class="legendDiv" id="legendDiv"><div id="legend-anchor">
<div id="legendWindow" class="legendWindow hide"></div></div></div>
<div id="scroller-anchor"></div><div id="scroller">                     
<div id="zoom_container"><div class="landmarks" data-show-at-zoom="100" data-allow-drag="false"></div></div><h3 id="canvas-title"></h3></div></div></div></div>
<div class="tirDIV"></div>
<table id="userdata" border="2">
<tr>

            <th width="10%"  axis="category_name">  Revision  Date </th>
            <th width="9%" align="center">  Document  Name </th>
            <th width="11%" align="center">  Department </th>
            <th width="46%" axis="category_name"> Description</th>
</tr>
    </table>


<script> 


 $.each(data.person, function(i, person) {
            var tblRow =  

"<tr><td>" + person.revisiondate +
"</td><td><a  target='_blank' href='"+ person.documentname.split('href=')[0]+"' >"+person.documentname.split('href=')[0]+"</a></td>"+
"<td>" + person.department +
"</td><td>" + person.description + "</td></tr>"

            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my .js file

```
 var data = {
        "person": [{
            "revisiondate": "21 April 2016",
        "documentname": "1658MC.pdf", 
            "department": "Sales",
            "description": "Bu dökümanın reviewed edilmesi gerekmekltedir"


        }, {
            "revisiondate": "16 April 2016",
            "documentname": "VCX16B.pdf",
            "department": "Enginnering",
        "description": "Not Available"

        }, {
            "revisiondate": "15 March 2016",
            "documentname": "AB36F.pdf",
        "department": "Custumer Services",
        "description":  "Not Available"

        }, {
            "revisiondate": "12 Agust 2016",
            "documentname": "FC25D.pdf",
            "department": "Technical Support",
        "description": "Not Available"

        }, {
            "revisiondate": "10 April 2017",
            "documentname": "00VR783A.pdf",
            "department": "Testing",
        "description": "Deneme"
        }]
    }
```

my html after run,

[Html picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROtyF.jpg)

First 4 file working good I mean, When I click, those file can open because those pdfs in same folder with html and this .split code triggers this pdfs with someway. My real problem is last pdf, last pdf in another folder and can't open because of file path. Href= not enough to describe path as first 4 file, And I need to write a file path to this code like

`C:\folder2\another.pdf`

How can I do that?

Comment: I've read this question a couple of times and I'm afraid that I still don't understand what the problem is, and what you want us to help with. On the assumption that English is not your first language - and that's fine - I wonder if you could explain this problem to a friend who might be able to offer an alternative, perhaps better, explanation of what you need. Please: take a few moments and read through the "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: Like @DavidThomas I don't understand where the `href` comes in...

Comment: It is not about language, it is about knowledge of codes and computer :) I read that, but I think nobody know .split tag as me. Because I couldn't find syntax. Interestingly it is working that wrong way. Want again, if your href specify a pdf file which in same folder with html, it is working. But my pdfs not in same folder with html. And I need to add some href thing to my code to get pdf from another folder like "C:\path\to\myfile.pdf" how can I do that. @DavidThomas

Comment: My intent wasn't to insult you, or dismiss your question, I want to help (as do others, that's why many of us spend our time here!), but unless I can understand your question I can't help, which is frustrating for me, because I want to help, and for you because you want the help.

Comment: Okkey see the editing. I tried to explain with all html and examples @DavidThomas